# Forgot to file 1065 for business that did not get any income. What do I do now?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business

It just came to my attention that my business missed the deadline for filing Form 1065. We also make no income.

How should I proceed from this point to make sure that the IRS does not come after us (4 members in an LLC)?

I've seen a note in the instructions of 1065 saying that businesses with no income don't need to file. Is this true?

Comment: @Ben Yes, it is.